# How to do Struts2 tiles in Netbeans

Tags: struts2

I'm new to Struts2 tiles. I just need how to configure my directory structure and what are the configuration files that are needed. Is an example available?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a look at the [proper place in the documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/tiles-plugin.html) would help ? The struts2 documentation can be hard to navigate.